How do you match on the last segment of any URL path in ASP.NET MVC?
I have several controller actions that should be triggered by the last URL segment. For example:
/this/is/a/path/do-this-thing
/this/is/also/a/path/do-this-other-thing

do-this-thing and do-this-other-thing are the parts I'm trying to match. The preceding paths could be anything (in the examples below, I attempt to capture what precedes as a variable called path).
I'm having trouble coding this. The wildcard pattern can only come at the end, so this does NOT work (it throws an exception):
{*path}/do-this-thing

I tried a regex...
{path:regex(.*)}/do-this-thing

...but that wouldn't match either.
This seems like such a simple thing, but I can't seem to find the right pattern.
Update: It has something to do with the slash. I've read in places that this will disrupt regex route parsing. See the first comment on the first answer.

Would using annotations not work and then returning different things in the Action Method? [Route("{*path}")] then pass the path as a parameter in your method and grab the end of it: var lastSegment = path?.Split('/').Last(); ??

@Bluetonic Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing. It just feels like a hack, and I feel like there has to be a "correct" way to do it...

I can suggest regex for this purpose (working alive at ASP.NET Core 8):
[Route(@"{location?}/{categoryurl:regex(^.+\-lists.html$)}")]
[Route(@"{categoryurl:regex(^.+\-lists.html$)}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> List(string categoryurl,string? location)

regards.
After checking comments
With standard routing in ASP.NET MVC, unlimited optional parameters are not possible!
I really don't recommend to do that, but the solution is writing your own dynamic routing by custom implementation of IRouter or DynamicRouteValueTransformer.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.dynamicroutevaluetransformer?view=aspnetcore-8.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#performance-guidance-for-routing

Thank you for this. It has something to do with the slash. Using your example, I did get it to match on something-lists.html, but I can't seem to form a regex that will match something/lists.html. It simply does not like a slash in the regex. I have verified that ^.+\/lists.html$ is a valid regex, but it doesn't seem to work in MVC routing.

Route[@"/this/is/a/path/{do-this-thing}"]
Route[@"/this/is/also/a/path/{do-this-other-thing}]
This is not so complex, if you can not imagine what combinations happening behid the science, trying to get all routes for app makes it easy to understand.
I mean someting like this; https://github.com/kobake/AspNetCore.RouteAnalyzer

The /this/is/a/path/ part is just an example. That could be anything, of of any length, with any number of slashes. It's not literal.
